# Angular set Sass root directory

Tags: angular, sass, webstorm

I'm trying to set up Sass/SCSS environment in Angular. But I'm having an issue with setting up custom root directory for Sass/SCSS imports.

### IDE:

I'm using the WebStorm IDE. I noticed this because of what does the WebStorm propose me when wring imports in SCSS files, so this also could be WebStorm related issue.

### Environment:

- Node 18
- Angular 15

### The problem is following:

I have this `anguler.json` configuration of SCSS:

```json
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  },
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
```

```json
"inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets"
],
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": []
},
"styles": [
  "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
  "src/styles.scss"
],
```

This is the configuration I have.
Tho I found a way to add additional roots. This doesn't allow me to have 100% over what paths are included / excluded. Because this still somehow includes the root of the project as well as the `node_modules`. I would like to set the root for imports to `src/styles`. Is this somehow possible with the `angular.json` config without using `ng eject` which I would like to avoid at all costs, because I don't want to deal with webpack either, or is it impossible because of how Angular is implemented. I did not found anything about this topic in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem solved another way:

I just noticed, I can use the ~ to access the root and this way I can actualy select from which **base url**, I import from, this way the issue is solved. whitout need to change the basic configration.

My problem was conflicting filenames mostly. Tho I'm still currious if this is possible or not. So If you have another solution I will still mark it as an answer.